# How can I deserialize Json array object like string?

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson

I have a DTO where Spring Boot tries to deserialize the request body, but, in this case, I need to deserialize a JSON array object as a String.

This is the JSON Request:

```
{
    "metadata": [{
        "example": 1
    }]
}
```

This is my dto:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class someDto implements Serializable {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = MetadataDeserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("metadata")
    @JsonbProperty("metadata")
    private String metadata;
}
```

I try to deserialize with this deserializer, but, It didn't work:

```
public class MetadataDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<String> {

    public MetadataDeserializer() {
        super(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return jsonParser.getValueAsString();
    }

}
```

I need to catch some similar like this:

```
"metadata": "[{ "example": 1 }]"
```

This deserializer is start when receiving the payload with @RequestBody.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that problem with this deserializer:

```
public class MetadataDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<String> {

    public MetadataDeserializer() {
        super(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        return jsonParser.readValueAsTree().toString();
    }

}
```